# grid with squares and vertical/horizontal rectangles

Tags: html, css, grid

A client would like a grid like this:
[image]

It includes squares as well as both horizontal and vertical rectangles.

I wonder if there's a way to achieve this without resorting to a big pile of absolute positions for every breakpoint...

If not, I'm willing to say that unit 5 can't be vertical, so the whole layout can be made of two rows. But I'm curious.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use a big <table> for it if you want, that's the easiest way.

Comment: I'm hoping to at least find examples of this layout being successfully executed before I attempt anything myself. The fact that I have not suggests to me that it's prohibitively complex.

Answer (score 2):

If responsiveness is not a problem you can easily do it with `<table>`s `<tr>`s and `<td>`s.

Something like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>6</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <table>
                    <tr>
                      <td colspan="2">4</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>7</td>
                      <td>8</td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </td>
                <td>5</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I haven't tested it I am not 100% sure this will do it, but you should play with these tags.
Also, you **have to** add some `width="NUMBERpx"` and `height="NUMBERpx"` attributes to your `<td>` elements. And some other css styles like padding margin etc.

I hope this helped you

Answer (score -3):

So I know that you should have tried to do it yourself first, but I need that sweet reputation points to be able to tell you that in the comments plus It gave me a learning opportunity. [JSFiddle:](http://tinyurl.com/ovxf7hx)  I had to split the 5 div into two parts and used bootstrap.

Comment: If I could split any element into two, I wouldn't have a problem. But I can't, that's what is so complicated about this layout and why I'm asking for help.

Comment: @ryancito Okay now I understand your question, I thought you were just looking for free labor. Next time make a JSFiddle or something to prove that you are least tried. I'll try to find a way.

Comment: Here's something that gives me hope: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout.html I"ll give it a try and be sure to report back. Thanks

Comment: @JohnZ answers like this are why you only have 28 rep